# How to make Outlook email notification envelope show in the unhidden notification area in system tray?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

How to make Outlook email notification show in the unhidden notification area in system tray?

The envelope shows up in the notification area when I maximize it but that's a problem if I get an email and I am not at the computer at the time. I need the envelope to show at all times. I am using Windows 7.

How to make the envelope icon visible all the time? If there's an add-on or third party thingy, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the arrow to expand the hidden System Tray icons:

[image: Arrow]

Click "Customize" link.

Scroll down and find the Envelope, and set it's option to "Show icon and notifications":

[image: Setting]

The envelope only shows up when Outlook is open, and you got a new mail item.  As soon as you [read](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/make-outlook-2007-mark-items-as-read-when-viewed-in-reading-pane/) any of the new messages the envelope goes away.